# Unity UNET network server not active when hosting a match on built game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am working on a multiplayer game on Unity using Unet, when i host a match by playing the game on the Unity editor, everything works as intended, but when i host a match on a built game (Running the game by clicking "build and run"), the networking functions don't work. I can't understand very well what is happening but i think i understood that the network server is someway inactive. This is weird because, as i said before the network server works when i host a match by playing the game in the Unity editor.

//this function spawns an enemy prefab

```
void Spawn()
   {
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawnPoint.position, 
        spawnPoint.rotation);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(enemy);
    }
```

/* this function is in the player script, when the enemy or the enemy bullet touches the player, the player gets damaged */

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        //Enemy enemy = hitInfo.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (hitInfo.tag == "Enemy" || hitInfo.tag == "EnemyBullet")
        {
            RpcTakeDamage(10, "hit by enemy");
        }
        //Instantiate(impactEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }

[ClientRpc]
    public void RpcTakeDamage(int _amount, string _sourceID)
    {
        if (!isHit)
        {
            StartCoroutine("HurtColor");
            currentHealth -= _amount;

            Debug.Log(transform.name + " now has " + currentHealth + " health ");

            if (currentHealth <= 0)
            {
                Die(_sourceID);
            }
        }

    }
```

/* this function is in the bullet behaviour script, when a bullet touches an enemy, the enemy gets destroyed. */

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        playerMovement player = hitInfo.GetComponent<playerMovement>();

        if (hitInfo.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            player = FindObjectOfType<playerMovement>();
            player.bombPower = player.bombPower + UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.1f, 0.5f);

            if(hitInfo.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                //Enemy enemy = FindObjectOfType<Enemy>();
                //enemy.currentHealth -= damage;
                player.CmdEnemyShot(hitInfo.transform.name, this.transform.name); //change this.transform.name with the player's name
            }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

Here are some error messages:

/* when a player joins the match, i get this warning, i can not understand what command can't be sent, probably is from the NetworkBehaviour class */

```
"Trying to send command for object without authority."
```

/* this error shows when an enemy gets spawned, the enemy is still visible but apparently only on client side */

```
"SpawnObject for EnemyUpRight(Clone) (UnityEngine.GameObject), 
NetworkServer is not active. Cannot spawn objects without an active server."
```

/* when an enemy bullet hit a plyer, this error shows up and the player can't take damage. */

```
"RPC Function RpcTakeDamage called on client."
```

//also this warning shows up

```
"Did not find target for sync message for 9"
```

//when an enemy is shot, the enemy doesn't die and this error shows up

```
"SpawnObject for Marisa_bullet(Clone) (UnityEngine.GameObject), NetworkServer is not active. Cannot spawn objects without an active server."
```

If you need my project to understand, [here is the link.](https://github.com/Ardoriccardo00/Touhou99.git)
The code can be a bit messy.

Comment: `RpcTakeDamage` may only be called by the server and is then distributed to all clients.  `player.CmdEnemyShot` can only be called if the `player` is the local player with a NetworkIdentity and local player authority.

Comment: Note that `FindObjectOfType<playerMovement>();` might return the wrong player if there are multiple players...

Comment: Also afaik `NetworkServer.Spawn(enemy);` can only be called by the server .. it seems that a client is trying to execute this.

Comment: 1)The funcion RpcTakeDamage is copyed from a tutorial, maybe it doesn't work because the game i'm programming is different.

Comment: 2) Should i write if(isLocalPlayer){player.CmdEnemyShot} ?

Comment: 3)How do i call it from the server? because if i write [Command] then it gives me an error saying "Trying to send command for object without authority". The enemy spawner is a gameobject and the enemy prefab is not spawned by the player, i don't know how to assing authority to a non player object.

Comment: @derHugo ↑↑↑ (previous questions)